# What clustering algorithm can be used with a distance matrix and without feaures?

Tags: clustering

I have a dataset of binary files. I can't do feature extraction on them. I just computed the distance between every pair of file in the dataset with a distance metric (NCD = Normalized Compression Distance). So I have a distance matrix.

My goal is to cluster these files. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: There are still a lot of clustering algorithms that will work, even if you only have a distance matrix & no longer have the raw data. Eg, if you are interested in hierarchical clustering, once you have a distance matrix you can do either single-linkage clustering or complete-linkage clustering w/o the original data.

Comment: How can I analyze the clusters?

Comment: What do you mean "analyze the clusters"?

Comment: Is there anyway I can show the clusters other than dendrograms?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm not familiar w/ NCD--I don't know what kind of distance it is. If you only have a distance matrix, you could do a multi-dimensional scaling to get points w/i an (arbitrary) space, & use that for plotting. The 1st 2 dimensions are analogous to the 1st 2 PCs in PCA.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it? or can you refer me to somewhere that I can read more about?

Comment: Try Googling it.

Comment: You can show the clusters in any kind of diagram of your cases that leaves you the possibility to show one further categorial dimension (typically color-coded or different symbols / patterns). E.g. I have hyperspectral data (spectra = my features with spatial information). So I can plot e.g. false color maps (spatial distritbution of clusters).

Comment: If you want visualisation, then the OPTICS landscape visualisation is quite nice. It is of course tied to the OPTICS method. As a side note, it is possible to visualise clusters produced by any type of algorithm onto the OPTICS landscape plot (but I don't know a general way of doing this), and your data is amenable to a wide range of clustering algorithms, including network-based algorithms. For the latter, you will need to work with similarities rather than distances.

Comment: @micans you can actually produce an OPTICS-like landscape for hierarchical clustering, too. It's closely related to a dendrogram. And to some extend, Silhouette is similar, too. But yes, OPTICS is probably a good choice to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many, many algorithms are based on distances only:

- hierarchical clustering, with most linkages (single-link etc.)
- DBSCAN
- OPTICS
- PAM (Partitioning around Medoids, aka k-medoids)
- Affinity propagation

Of course there are also a number of methods that need coordinates. In particular

- Centroid-based methods such as k-means need coordinates to compute the centroid
- Grid-based methods such as DENCLUE need coordinates to compute a grid

Answer (score 1):

so if you are able to do pair-wise distance calculation on your data, then you can certainly cluster your data with, for instance, **k-means**, which is based entirely on pair-wide distance calculation (though between each data point and a group of composite data point (aka ***centroids***)

if you are not familiar with *k-means*, it works like so:

- choose N, an integer value that represents the number of centroids,
  cluster centers (some refinements to the basic algorithm include a
  step to calculate the optimum number of centroids, eg, k-means plus)
- select N data points at random; these are your centroids at t=0
  (iteration 1)
- for each remaining data point, calculate the pairwise distance from
  each of the N centroids; the centroid that give the smallest value
  (the centroid the point is closest to) is the centroid that data
  point is assigned to for iteration 1
- now your data is partitioned into N groups; for each group of data
  points, calculate a single mean data point--these N points are the
  new centroids at iteration 2
- repeat the step above until some stopping criteria is reached (eg,
  less than one percent mean diff between the centroids in two
  consecutive iterations)

Comment: -1: k-means is **not** based on pairwise distances. On the contrary. It is based on sum of squared 1d deviations from centroids only.

Comment: @Anony You might be a little too harsh here. If we read this answer just a little more generously and understand "based on ... distance" to include *squared* distances, then it is a mathematical fact that one-half the sum of pairwise squared distances within a cluster equals the sum of squared distances to the centroids.

Comment: @whuber The reason for the -1 is mostly that computing distances to **centroids** is exactly what is not possible here. He is clustering executable files (see his previous question), which he compares by compression distance. What is the centroid of a bunch of executables?